# callout error with out callouts in my class

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, developer

Hi I have below class and test class.

### I am getting the "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out" error.

```
Public class GE_OG_CalcCustomerCreditLimit
{
//AfterInsert
public void calcCustomerCreditLimitAfterInsert(List<Opportunity>  newOpptyList)
{

    List<Opportunity>  newOpptyList1= (List<Opportunity>)newOpptyList;
    Set<Id> setAccId = new Set<Id>();
    List<GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c> lstCustCreditHistoryUpdate = new List<GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c>();

    for (Opportunity Opp : newOpptyList1) 
    {


            if((Opp.StageName=='Active - Commit' || Opp.StageName=='Closed Won')&& (Opp.GE_ES_R_Status__c !=null)  && (Opp.GE_ES_R_Status__c != 'R0') && Opp.GE_HQ_Business_Tier1__c == 'Oil & Gas (O&G)')
            {
                if(Opp.AccountId != null)
                {
                setAccId.add(Opp.AccountId);
                }
            }

    } 
    if(!setAccId.isEmpty())
    {

        for(GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c Cch: [select Id, GE_HQ_Acct_Cr_Limit__c, GE_HQ_Cr_Limit_Exceeded__c, GE_HQ_Tot_AR_s__c, GE_HQ_Acc__c from GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c where GE_HQ_Acc__c in: setAccId])
        {
            GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c CchUpdate = new GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c(Id=Cch.Id);
            CchUpdate.GE_HQ_Acct_Cr_Limit__c = Cch.GE_HQ_Acct_Cr_Limit__c;
            lstCustCreditHistoryUpdate.add(CchUpdate);
        }
    }
    if(!lstCustCreditHistoryUpdate.isEmpty())
    {
        update lstCustCreditHistoryUpdate ;
    }




}
//afterInser closed

//for AfterUpdate
public void calcCustomerCreditLimitAfterUpdate(List<Opportunity>  newOpptyList,Map<Id,Opportunity>  OldMapOpportunity)
{
            List<Opportunity>  newOpptyList1= (List<Opportunity>)newOpptyList;

             Map<Id,Opportunity>  oldMapOpportunity1=(Map<Id,Opportunity>)  OldMapOpportunity; 


    Set<Id> setAccId = new Set<Id>();
    List<GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c> lstCustCreditHistoryUpdate = new List<GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c>();

    for (Opportunity Opp : newOpptyList1) 
    {


            Opportunity OppBeforeUpdate = oldMapOpportunity1.get(Opp.Id); 
            if(OppBeforeUpdate.Amount != Opp.Amount || OppBeforeUpdate.StageName != Opp.StageName || OppBeforeUpdate.GE_ES_R_Status__c != Opp.GE_ES_R_Status__c)
            {
                System.debug('In Update====');
                if(Opp.AccountId != null){setAccId.add(Opp.AccountId);}
            }        


    } 
    if(!setAccId.isEmpty())
    {

        for(GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c Cch: [select Id, GE_HQ_Acct_Cr_Limit__c, GE_HQ_Cr_Limit_Exceeded__c, GE_HQ_Tot_AR_s__c, GE_HQ_Acc__c from GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c where GE_HQ_Acc__c in: setAccId])
        {
            GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c CchUpdate = new GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c(Id=Cch.Id);
            CchUpdate.GE_HQ_Acct_Cr_Limit__c = Cch.GE_HQ_Acct_Cr_Limit__c;
            lstCustCreditHistoryUpdate.add(CchUpdate);
        }
    }
    if(!lstCustCreditHistoryUpdate.isEmpty())
    {
        update lstCustCreditHistoryUpdate ;
    }


}
// for AfterUpdate close
}
```

### testclass:

```
@isTest
private class GEOGCalcCustomerCreditLimit_Test{
static testMethod void GEOGCalcCustomerCreditLimit_Test(){ 

    //User usr = new User(LastName='test user',Alias='tuser',DefaultGroupNotificationFrequency='N',DigestFrequency='N',Email='testuser@ge.com',Username='testuserr2@ge.com',EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',LocaleSidKey='IN',ProfileId= ProfId,TimeZoneSidKey='Asia/Kolkata',UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin=false,UserPermissionsMarketingUser=false,UserPermissionsOfflineUser=false);
    //Insert usr;
    Account Acc = new Account();
    Acc.Name = 'Test account';
    Acc.BillingCountry = 'USA';
    Acc.ShippingCountry = 'USA';
    Acc.ShippingState = 'AT';
    Acc.ShippingCity = 'TestShipping City';
    Acc.ShippingStreet = 'Test Shipping Street';
    Acc.ShippingPostalCode = '101010';
    Acc.GE_HQ_Request_Status__c = 'CMF Approved';
    insert Acc;  

    GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c Cch = new GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c();
    Cch.GE_HQ_Acc__c = Acc.Id;
    Cch.GE_HQ_Acct_Cr_Limit__c = 2500000;
    Cch.GE_HQ_Cr_Limit_Remaining__c = 1000;
    Cch.GE_HQ_Tot_AR_s__c = 2000; 
    insert Cch;

 GE_Configuration_Setting__c cs= new GE_Configuration_Setting__c();
 cs.GE_OG_DTS_OpptyID__c=5490;
 cs.GE_PWNUC_Oppty_ID__c=5490;
 cs.GE_OGGS_Oppty_Id__c=5490;
 cs.GE_OG_Oppty_Id_Counter__c=5490;
 cs.GE_OG_PII_OIDCnt__c=5490;
 cs.GE_OG_SS_WSIDCntr__c=5490;
 cs.name='OG Counter';

 insert cs;



    GE_ES_Project__c prj = new GE_ES_Project__c();
    prj.Name = 'TestProject1';
    prj.GE_OG_SS_First_Oil_Date__c=Date.today();
    insert prj;


     Opportunity oppty = new Opportunity();
    oppty.RecordTypeId =[select id,name from recordtype where name like 'Grouped Flow' limit 1].id;
    oppty.Name= 'TestOppty1';
    oppty.GE_ES_Project__c = prj.Id;
    oppty.AccountId = Acc.Id;
    oppty.Type = 'Primary';
    oppty.StageName = 'Active - Commit';
    oppty.GE_ES_R_Status__c = 'R1 Submitted';
    oppty.GE_HQ_Business_Tier1__c = 'Oil & Gas (O&G)';
    oppty.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
    oppty.GE_ES_Bid_Due_Date__c = Date.today();
    oppty.CloseDate= Date.today();
    oppty.Amount= 1000;
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Commercial_Center__c= 'Bari';
    oppty.GE_OG_Stream__c = 'Core Services - Aberdeen';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Quote_Type__c = 'Budget';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Industrial_Sector__c = 'LNG';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Subsector__c = 'CCR';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Application_Center__c = 'Bari';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_RFQ_Received_Date__c = Date.today();
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Proposal_Assesment__c = 'Tech & Comm With Same Due Date';
    //oppty.GE_OG_Oppty_End_User__c = buyer.Id;
    oppty.End_User__c = Acc.Id;
    oppty.GE_ES_OPPTY_CM__c = 35;
    insert oppty;

    }

    static testMethod void GEOGCalcCustomerCreditLimit_Test1()
    { 

GE_Profile__c profile=new GE_Profile__c();
profile.name='GE_ES System Integration';
profile.Profile_SFDC_ID__c=[select id, name from Profile where  name = 'GE_ES System Integration' limit 1].id;
insert profile;

 Account Acc = new Account();
    Acc.Name = 'Test account';
    Acc.BillingCountry = 'USA';
    Acc.ShippingCountry = 'USA';
    Acc.ShippingState = 'AT';
    Acc.ShippingCity = 'TestShipping City';
    Acc.ShippingStreet = 'Test Shipping Street';
    Acc.ShippingPostalCode = '101010';
    Acc.GE_HQ_Request_Status__c = 'CMF Approved';
    insert Acc;  

    GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c Cch = new GE_HQ_CUST_CREDIT_HIST__c();
    Cch.GE_HQ_Acc__c = Acc.Id;
    Cch.GE_HQ_Acct_Cr_Limit__c = 2500000;
    Cch.GE_HQ_Cr_Limit_Remaining__c = 1000;
    Cch.GE_HQ_Tot_AR_s__c = 2000; 
    insert Cch;

 GE_Configuration_Setting__c cs= new GE_Configuration_Setting__c();
 cs.GE_OG_DTS_OpptyID__c=5490;
 cs.GE_PWNUC_Oppty_ID__c=5490;
 cs.GE_OGGS_Oppty_Id__c=5490;
 cs.GE_OG_Oppty_Id_Counter__c=5490;
 cs.GE_OG_PII_OIDCnt__c=5490;
 cs.GE_OG_SS_WSIDCntr__c=5490;
 cs.name='OG Counter';

 insert cs;



    GE_ES_Project__c prj = new GE_ES_Project__c();
    prj.Name = 'TestProject1';
    prj.GE_OG_SS_First_Oil_Date__c=Date.today();
    insert prj;


     Opportunity oppty = new Opportunity();
    oppty.RecordTypeId =[select id,name from recordtype where name like 'Grouped Flow' limit 1].id;
    oppty.Name= 'TestOppty1';
    oppty.GE_ES_Project__c = prj.Id;
    oppty.AccountId = Acc.Id;
    oppty.Type = 'Primary';
    oppty.StageName = 'Active - Commit';
    oppty.GE_ES_R_Status__c = 'R1 Submitted';
    oppty.GE_HQ_Business_Tier1__c = 'Oil & Gas (O&G)';
    oppty.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD';
    oppty.GE_ES_Bid_Due_Date__c = Date.today();
    oppty.CloseDate= Date.today();
    oppty.Amount= 1000;
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Commercial_Center__c= 'Bari';
    oppty.GE_OG_Stream__c = 'Core Services - Aberdeen';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Quote_Type__c = 'Budget';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Industrial_Sector__c = 'LNG';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Subsector__c = 'CCR';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Application_Center__c = 'Bari';
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_RFQ_Received_Date__c = Date.today();
    oppty.GE_OG_TM_Proposal_Assesment__c = 'Tech & Comm With Same Due Date';
    //oppty.GE_OG_Oppty_End_User__c = buyer.Id;
    oppty.End_User__c = Acc.Id;
    oppty.GE_ES_OPPTY_CM__c = 35;
    insert oppty;

  test.starttest();

oppty.name= 'hai';
update oppty;

 test.stoptest();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As salesforce documentation, you can not perform database (DML) to call before making external calls.

Source:[Source](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_dml.htm)

Check if you have any trigger that performs some external call.

Comment: This class is the related to trigger only . can you please tell me clearly

Comment: You could post the complete exception?